# Occurrence of the most frequent value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am stuck on a problem where I need to find the count of the most frequent value.

With this I will get the Table with all the different cars, their problem count and the most frequent problem.

Now I want to count how many times does the most frequent problem occur. I think I need to do something with subqueries but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone help me out or lead me to the right direction please?

Comment: Great to prepare the fiddle, but the expected result would be helpful, too

Comment: Thanks, added the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used, as you, that strange feature of mysql, using a column that is not grouped and not aggregated, and made the needed subselect:

```
SELECT c.Model, 
COUNT(j.JobType) AS ProblemCount,
j.JobType as MostCommonProblemType
, (select count(*) from Jobs where jobs.Jobtype = j.JobType 
   and CarId in (select Id from Cars c2 where c2.model = c.model) 
  ) as ProblemCount
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN Jobs j ON j.CarId = c.Id 
GROUP BY c.Model
ORDER BY COUNT(j.JobType) DESC;
```

**Output**

| Model | ProblemCount | MostCommonProblemType | ProblemCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ford Mustang | 8 | Engine | 4 |
| Ford Focus | 6 | Engine | 3 |
| Ford Puma | 2 | Maintenance | 2 |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef148/1632)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Did I get you right, that you would like to count the occurence of the most frequent ProblemCount?

If so: This is not the cleanest solution, but I hope, this will help you.

```
SELECT
  ProblemCount,
  COUNT(ProblemCount)
FROM(
  SELECT Cars.Model, 
  COUNT(Jobs.JobType) AS ProblemCount, 
  Jobs.JobType AS MostCommonProblemType
  FROM Cars
  INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.CarId = Cars.Id 
  GROUP BY Cars.Model
) A
WHERE ProblemCount = (SELECT MAX(B.ProblemCount) FROM (SELECT 
  COUNT(Jobs.JobType) AS ProblemCount
  FROM Cars
  INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.CarId = Cars.Id 
  GROUP BY Cars.Model) B)
GROUP BY ProblemCount;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what exactly the output should be but here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef148/1600
What I need to find is the occurrence of the most frequent problem TYPE. Sorry if that was unclear from the thread. The solution does not need to be clean, just something that would work that I could look and understand from how to make such queries.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a window function, `rank()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT c.Model, COUNT(*) AS ProblemCount, 
             j.JobType AS MostCommonProblemType,
             RANK) OVER (PARTITION BY c.Model ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ranking
      FROM Cars c INNER JOIN
           Jobs j
           ON j.CarId = c.Id 
      GROUP BY c.Model, j.JobType
     ) m
WHERE ranking = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88eef593ded3e32f59f6f99a4fa27de0) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that use a table aliases; this makes the query easier to write and to read.  Also, you can use `COUNT(*)`.  There seems to be no need to check if `Job(JobType)` is not `NULL`, which is what `COUNT(j.JobType)` does.

Comment: I'm getting an error (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as ranking FROM Cars c INNER JOIN Jobs' at line 4) when trying this. Link to fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ef148/1588

Comment: I think the problem is that the sqlfiddle is on 5.6 version where the window functions are not yet introduced. Do you have any idea how to do it that would be supported by 5.6 version of mysql?

Comment: @Randomando . . . I actually misunderstood the problem, so I fixed the answer and added a db<>fiddle, which does support MySQL 8.

Comment: Sorry I think I did not explain my problem clear enough. What I need is a result like I have updated on the original post.

And it should work on mysql version 5.6. Nevertheless thank you for taking time and trying to help me out.